# everything looks OK but JSON returns empty in Android

Tags: php, android, json

I've run a similar code successfully before, but this time it's not working! I really can't understand why.

Any ideas?

```
public class SingleMenuItemActivity extends Activity {

private static String url = "http://www.tatangalar.com/android/takim_detay.php?takimID=5";

private static final String TAG_MACBILGISI = "son10mac";
private static final String TAG_10 = "10";
private static final String TAG_9 = "9";

JSONArray sonuclar = null;
String filan;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    setContentView(R.layout.benim2);        

    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

    try {
        sonuclar = json.getJSONArray(TAG_MACBILGISI);

        for(int i = 0; i < sonuclar.length(); i++){

            JSONObject c = sonuclar.getJSONObject(i);

            String s_on = c.getString(TAG_10);
            String s_dokuz = c.getString(TAG_9);

            filan = s_on;

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    TextView txtsecilen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.son9); 

    txtsecilen.setText(filan);

}
}
```

Comment: please debug your project and watch if JSONObject json has any values returned from the url.

Comment: and what is the error you get, can you paste error stack trace.

Comment: this link will guide you as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android

Comment: I got the solution; I've just changed getString to optString and it worked! thanks :)

Comment: glad to hear that, tatanga :)

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` because of this line of code:

```
jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
```

This used to be a warning, but on newer versions of the Android OS it is not permitted. You must not access the internet from the main UI Thread, such as in your `onCreate()` method. Send your internet command from a separate `runOnUIThread()`, `Thread/Runnable` or `AsyncTask` and your `NetworkOnMainThreadException` problem will be solved.

Android disallows this to make sure you don't hang the UI during long tasks by forcing you to do time consuming activity in alternate Threads.

**Example**:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ...
        jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        ...
    }
});
```

You will probably want to display a `ProgressDialog` and close it when the `Thread` finishes. An `AsyncTask` involves a few more steps, but is extremely well suited to this task because it provides hooks for displaying, updating, and dismissing your `ProgressDialog`.

Comment: Which codes be written in runOnUIThread() my friend? i've tried somethings after your post but i didn't get values again : (

Comment: there is a certain thing which is that android couldn't get values from JSON. i don't know why..

Comment: I got the solution; I've just changed getString to optString and it worked! thanks :)